# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) but not for Node.js

Tags: mariadb, passwords

I recently tried to login into my MariaDB database via shell and got this error even though I'm 100% sure the password is correct:

```
mysql -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm running a node.js server that connects to the same database with the same password with no problems...

Comment: Are you connecting from the same machine that is running mariaDB?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I am

Answer (score 1):

You don't have privileges to connect to the `root` mysql user. Simply use `sudo`:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Enter password that you use on your machine, after that enter password to the `root` mysql user.